# How to scrape the website once your IP has been blacklisted

Tags: python, proxy, request

I am scraping a website where my IP has been blacklisted. I can access the website only when routed through a proxy ( I use HidemyIP chrome extension)

I need to scrape the website to mine some data. I am using Python ( `requests`, `Beautifulsoup`) to extract data.

I tried using open proxy but it does not seem to work. Here is the command I am using :

```
http_proxy  = "http://10.10.1.10:3128"
https_proxy = "https://10.10.1.11:1080"

proxy = { 
              "http"  : http_proxy, 
              "https" : https_proxy
            }
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10, proxies=proxy)
```

I was wondering in addition to the above, if there is any other way, we could configure either in Windows ( or router) to route through virtual proxy to avoid being blacklisted ?

Comment: I don't have the time to write a full answer but this seems like a complete solution using the packages you prefer: https://codelike.pro/create-a-crawler-with-rotating-ip-proxy-in-python/

Comment: I tried these IP's from sslproxies.org None of them seem to work